# Tibero Create Database TBR-7067: Specified database name 'dbnewproj' doest not match parameter database name int tip file 'tibero'

Tags: docker, tibero

I'm new to this Tibero database, the installation of this to a docker container is interesting. But upon creating a new database, that's where I'm struggling now.

I'm trying to create a separate, new tibero database which we'll be using for a new project.
Reading the online Tibero 6 Online Manual, I don't see a guide on how to create a new database. I dunno if I'm missing something I checked it many times but it's not there.
[Tibero 6 Online Manual - Tibero  Administrator's Guide](https://technet.tmaxsoft.com/upload/download/online/tibero/pver-20150504-000002/index.html)

I learned about the `CREATE DATABASE` syntax from the reference guides we received that are written in Korean.
Link is here [Set up Tibero on Docker](https://xeppetto.github.io/%EC%86%8C%ED%94%84%ED%8A%B8%EC%9B%A8%EC%96%B4/WSL-and-Docker/16-Docker-Tibero/)
I tried creating a new database about 3 times but I always get this error:

```
7067: Specified database name \'%1$s\' does not match parameter database name in tip file \'%2$s\'.
```

On Tibero Error Reference Guide it's described like this

[image]

I have questions on this as well. Where can I find this parameter file the guide is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I read again the guide written in korean, when tibero license is a demo / trial license, the database creation is limited to name 'tibero' only.
This could help future users of tibero as future reference.